# firebase hosting script path not relative to current sub folder path

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Bellow is my public folder structure hosted on firebase.

When i go to this url path   http://.../dist/app.html the app.html loads but none of the scripts load. the only way to load the scripts is by adding 'dist' to the script path like shown in the pic (giving it full path of the scripts instead of relative path from the current folder)

If i open app.html on local machine it wont load the scripts because 'dist/[scriptNameHere].js' files does not exist.

So why does the hosted public folder require full path of the files?

I would like to import my scripts relative to the current path

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>  etc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was siting right in front of me.

In your index.html change `<base href="/">` to a path you want your path resolve to start from

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting will deploy everything relative to what is specified as the `public` directory in the `hosting` config of `firebase.json`. If you are building a single-page app, you will most likely want to use absolute URLs to reference bundles, so `/inline.bundle.js`, for example.

To check out how things are going to work once deployed, you should use `firebase serve` in your project directory. That will spin up a local server that should behave just like the deployed version -- you can test things out there and deploy when they look good.

Comment: its not a single-page app. Thanks for the firebase serve idea. help test locally instead of deploy each time.